# ByRef Argument type mismatch on just changing the variable position in declaration

Tags: vba, byref

I have defined a function in VBA as follows:

```
Sub TestFunction()    
Dim ArrayLength, IDvariable, IDComparisonResult, PreArrayLength As Integer
ReDim NodesArray(0)
PreArrayLength = 0
IDvariable = 0
.
.
Sort PreArrayLength
End Sub
```

whereas the function called is as follows:

```
Sub Sort (PreArrayLength As Integer)
.
.
.
end sub
```

Above function runs nicely but if I change declaration in TestFunction() as

```
Dim ArrayLength, IDvariable, PreArrayLength, IDComparisonResult As Integer
```

my code gives me an error "ByRef Argument type mismatch" indicating the line

```
Sort PreArrayLength
```

Can anyone point the mistake I am making in declaration or understanding the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as this :

```
Dim ArrayLength As Integer, _
    IDvariable As Integer, _
    PreArrayLength As Integer, _
    IDComparisonResult As Integer
```

Because when you use `Dim`, you have to specify for each variable what type is it, the previous code was declaring the first three as `Variant` and **only the last one as `Integer`**!

Reference: [How to declare variables in VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241.aspx)